# React-Native check image url

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

I am trying to check if the url of an image is 404 or not. The problem is that the function is returning undefined. Why is this happening?

If I console.log the status of the res it does show 404 so the if statement is being executed.

```
function checkImageURL(url){
 fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
    if(res.status == 404){
      console.log(res.status)
      return <Image source={require('./Images/default.png')}/>
    }else{
      return <Image source={{uri: `${url}`}}  />
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: Check out this to see if this is better for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675678/7602110

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are not returning anything on error response.

add .catch and return a component or null in that. for eg

```js
function checkImageURL(URL) {
  fetch(URL)
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status == 404) {
        return <Image source={require('./Images/default.png')} />;
      } else {
        return <Image source={{ uri: `${url}` }} />;
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return <Image source={require('./Images/default.png')} />;
    });
}
```

Comment: The catch statement did work I think because the fetch is getting an error its just getting a 404 status response.

Comment: So it solved your problem . Then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Although the selected answer solves the problem in question, the overarching problem here I notice is the way the OP is handling an image uri that returns a 404. If your intention is to have a fallback image in the case that an image's uri is invalid for whatever reason (any 400ish response), I'd recommend leveraging the `onError` `<Image/>` prop.

I have an `<Avatar/>` component that uses this prop:

```
import { Image, ImageStyle } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { avatarPlaceholder } from '../../assets/images'

interface Props {
  avatar: string;
  style: ImageStyle;
}

const Avatar = React.memo((props: Props) => {
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(true)
  const { avatar, style } = props

  return (
    <Image
      onError={() => setValid(false)}
      style={[{
        resizeMode: "cover",
        borderRadius: 1000,
      }, style]}
      source={{ uri: valid ? avatar : avatarPlaceholder }}
    />
  )
})

export default Avatar
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you don't need to check if the image response status it's not `404` to be able to display it. You just need to fetch your data and store it in your state, then check if the image can be displayed like the example below.

I am not exactly what are you trying to build but in my opinion, you should never make a request to fetch an image.

There is a [`defaultSource`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#defaultsource) prop now.

```js
<Image
  source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/image.png' }}
  style={{ height: 200, width: 200 }}
  defaultSource={defaultImg}
/>
```

Check the snack https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/defaultimage

Comment: This does not work. If your some-url path is not a valid image, it will show empty image instead of the defaultImg

Comment: Agreed, this does not work, exactly as The1993 said.

Comment: I have updated the answer and it should be working fine now

Comment: Ahh yes this is a huge life saver. I was trying to use the on error to change the state but I was often mapping over multiple avatars so one 404 would set them all to false. I knew there was a better way.